# Simulate the Accelerometer on desktop (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, simulate

I am looking to simulate the Accelerometer on the 'desktop'. The problem is I can't seem to correctly override the values since 'accelerationIncludingGravity' or 'devicemotion' come back as 'undefined' on desktop. What I would like to do is manually set this value like so:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
    accelerationIncludingGravity.z = 100;
});
```

Is there anyway to do this? I need to do this in javascript.

Comment: What language/environment/... are you using? It's unclear

Comment: Sorry Karel, I updated the original question to be more clear. I am looking to achieve this in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need hardware or emulation for the values to be present. Google Chrome's dev tools has accelerometer emulation.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#device-sensors

Comment: Hey Bitwise, thanks for the quick response. I know that you need an emulation but is there no way to manually override or create these values? I've seen a similar thing done for touch events on desktop so I am curious if the same applies for the accelerometer.

Comment: Sure, but it's going to be more work without using the emulator. You'd need to craft your own events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events and then model the event data with applicable values. This is a pretty simple demo for reference: http://sandbox.juurlink.org/accelerometer/

Comment: You're welcome :) If I answered your question, would you mind accepting my answer by clicking the check mark on the left?

Comment: Is this still available? I'm on Version 110.0.5481.100 (Official Build) (arm64) and this does not seem to be an accelerometer emulator in dev tools anymore